# Installing large package throwing "no space" error

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, package-management

Im trying to install unity3D on my persitsent Ubuntu linuy, the stick is 10+ gb and the persistent part about 4GB.

But whenever i run `dpkg -i unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb` it takes a while and then throws this error:

```
(Reading database ... 192291 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking unity-editor (5.3.5f1) over (5.3.5f1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport/Variations/win64_nondevelopment_mono/player_win_x64.pdb' to '/opt/Unity/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/WindowsStandaloneSupport/Variations/win64_nondevelopment_mono/player_win_x64.pdb.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb
```

I the googled the problem and read some answers like clearing the cache, unfortunately neither of the solutions worked.
This is what `df -a` prints:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ df -a
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
sysfs                  0       0         0    - /sys
proc                   0       0         0    - /proc
udev             4048568       0   4048568   0% /dev
devpts                 0       0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs             812644    9656    802988   2% /run
/dev/sdf1       15257600 5681272   9576328  38% /cdrom
/dev/loop1       1399936 1399936         0 100% /rofs
/cow             4062904 3439240    413952  90% /
securityfs             0       0         0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs            4063216     144   4063072   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            4063216       0   4063216   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/pstore
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
systemd-1              0       0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
mqueue                 0       0         0    - /dev/mqueue
hugetlbfs              0       0         0    - /dev/hugepages
debugfs                0       0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
tracefs                -       -         -    - /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
fusectl                0       0         0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
tmpfs            4063216     132   4063084   1% /tmp
tmpfs             812644      48    812596   1% /run/user/999
gvfsd-fuse             0       0         0    - /run/user/999/gvfs
```

EDIT: The unity .deb file is 1.2G according to `du -sh unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb`

Comment: How large is `unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb`? Can you run `du -sh unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb` and add the output to the question?

Comment: @Peschke it is 1.2G

Comment: I get this problem too, but when I put the Unity3d installation `.deb` in my SD Card in my Chromebook and execute the `dpkg -i Unityxxxx.deb` from my SD Card, it works. Can you try it, please?

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` is not lying, you do not have enough space to install `unity-editor-5.3.5f1+20160525_amd64.deb`.

Your `root` filesystem only has 404.25 MB of space available, and you are trying to install a package that is 1.2 GB.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/cow             4062904 3439240    413952  90% /
```

413952 KB available. 413952 KB == 404.25 MB

Comment: so... can it be installed to another location or can the root file system be expanded?

Comment: @Minzkraut, no that is the drawback to using a LiveCD type install on a USB disk.  The only way to expand the root filesystem is to install Ubuntu to an actual HDD